# Convert a node from one content type to another, using a rule set

Tags: 7, rules, tokens

I want to convert a node from one content type ("Project") to another one ("Project follow up"), basing on the comparison between the current date (using PHP) and the value of a field date ("Project signup date," which is a CCK date field). Currently, I am using a rule set that will be scheduled based on a check that a rule does when the project is created. The rule set than checks (upon a successful cron run) if the date is higher than the field date (using the date timestamp); the rule set will then convert the node from "Project" to "Project followup."

As I keep getting errors when testing the rule/rule set, I must ask if I'm doing it right. What are the proper PHP evaluation and token replacement pattern? The following are the replacement tokens, and my default PHP code.

#### Replacement tokens

```
[node:field_pdate-value]     The raw date value.
[node:field_pdate-view]      The formatted date.
[node:field_pdate-timestamp] The raw date timestamp.
[node:field_pdate-yyyy]      Date year (four digit)
[node:field_pdate-yy]        Date year (two digit)
[node:field_pdate-month]     Date month (full word)
[node:field_pdate-mon]       Date month (abbreviated)
[node:field_pdate-mm]        Date month (two digit, zero padded)
[node:field_pdate-m]         Date month (one or two digit)
[node:field_pdate-ww]        Date week (two digit)
[node:field_pdate-date]      Date date (YYYY-MM-DD)
[node:field_pdate-datetime]  Date datetime (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS)
[node:field_pdate-day]       Date day (full word)
[node:field_pdate-ddd]       Date day (abbreviation)
[node:field_pdate-dd]        Date day (two digit, zero-padded)
[node:field_pdate-d]         Date day (one or two digit)
[node:field_pdate-dS]        Date day (one or two digit) with ordinal suffix (st, nd, rd or th)
[node:field_pdate-time]      Time H:i
```

#### PHP code

```
php echo time();
```

Comment: What kind of comparison do you want to do?

Comment: The PHP code is not making any comparison; it is just outputting the time of when it is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node Convert might help you with the node conversion from one type to another. http://drupal.org/project/node_convert

I'm not sure if you can use this module to do it programmatically, but it might help to look at this structure and run something similar on a cron job.

Comment: Node_convert has good field-mapping support: how to deal with the data in fields when migrating from one type to another. That is the hardest part of migrating.